# asp.net mvc form authentication works locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net, iis

On local host, I am able to use form authentication and it works. However, when I publish to DEV server, it just keeps going back to login page. Occasionally, I see this error message in event viewer. Ideas?

Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.

Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired. 
Event time: 11/11/2016 4:08:31 PM 
Event time (UTC): 11/11/2016 10:08:31 PM 
Event ID: bc007c88643c421681a46b473f5ce254 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50202

Comment: Can you show error

Comment: I am getting the same ERROR do you have any solution to this?